# How to override admin.ModelAdmin class from site-packages?

Tags: django

i want to override help_text for some model in site-packages. but i obviously can't just change it in package because it will not be saved after updating packages and some other actions.

```
    crontab = models.ForeignKey(
        CrontabSchedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('crontab'), help_text=_('Use one of interval/crontab'),
    )
```

probably i have to create some app and override the whole thing in admin.py but i'm not sure it is a good practice.

also there is option with localize i consider but i still will have to create an app for that.

Comment: you can use Monkey patching in your project or fork the third-party package.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911110/14509153

Comment: Can you just change the text where you want it to display rather than patching the model just to change the help text?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to unregister the model right before you register a custom admin for the model.
So you don't actually change the help_text, but you can create a custom admin, on which you can do as you please.
It would look something like this, with `django_celery_beat.models.TaskResult` as an example:

```
[structure]
app/
   admin/
         init.py  # import your admin here to include it
         ...
         taskresult.py
   [...]
```

`admin/taskresult.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult

from app.admin.custom_filters import TaskResultFilter


admin.site.unregister(TaskResult)


@admin.register(TaskResult)
class TaskResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    This admin is your oyster.
    """
    pass
```

Now you have an admin page that you can customise without hacking the original package, model or admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate file/folder.

`custom/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Override function/properties
```

Then in your `<app>/admin.py` inherit from custom class you've created

```
from custom.admin import CustomModelAdmin

class ClassName(CustomModelAdmin):
    # Your code
```

Comment: ```from django.contrib import admin

class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    # Override function/properties```

to override class method here i have to import from django_celery_beat.admin.py?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask

PeriodicTask._meta.get_field('crontab').help_text = ('overriding text')
```

worked just fine.