# Increasing User model's field length without overriding

Tags: django, python-2.7

Using django 1.9

In our project we decided to use `e-mail` field instead of `username` field of `User`.

We tried to do it without overriding `django.contrib.auth`'s `User` model, so just hid the `username` field in registration form to fill it with e-mail field's data. The problem is the username field has `max_len=30`, e-mail field - `max_len=254`.

Which is the best approach to solve it without overriding User model, if possible?

Comment: You don't override it, you create your own user model, there shouldn't be a lot of work involved providing you've been referencing the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` rather than the `User` class

Comment: Well, you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django but it is always advised to create a custom user model that suits your need instead of monkey patching