# Best practice to update Django contrib

Tags: python, django, mixpanel

I'd like to make some changes to `def login` and `def logout` in `django.contrib.auth` `__init.py__`. Specifically I want to add a mixpanel event to user login and logout.

I know I can do this by editing the file directly, although I assume this is not recommended due to version control / etc.

What's the best / easiest way to override these functions cleanly?

Comment: Recommended method is to use your own custom User model, but you can also monkey patch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to change the code at all. Both login and logout send [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/); you can write code that listens to those signals and create your mixpanel events.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples?