# Rank of users - Django

Tags: python, django

How can I rank the users based on their total number of posts. 
example  First : total number of posts 1-10 
Second : total number of posts 11-20
Third : total number of posts 21-30

models.py

```
from django.db import models
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def count_posts_of(user):
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ordering `User`s by the number of posts

We can annotate a `User` with the number of `Post`s, and then use `order_by` on that annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(nposts=Count('post')).order_by('-nposts')
```

Here the dash (`-`) means that we sort in *descending* order (so from many posts to few posts). If you remove the dash, then it orders in *ascending* order.

## Assigning a *numerical* rank to the `User`s

We can also assign a *numerical* rank to each user (so 1-10 map to `1`, 11-20 map to `2`, etc.) by adding some extra annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

User.objects.annotate(
    nposts=Count('post'),
    nrank=Func(F('nposts') / 10, function='CEIL'),
).order_by('-nposts')
```

## Mapping the *numeric* rank to an *textual* rank

We can map this rank to a textual rank, by defining for example a `@property`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import User

RANK_TEXTS = ['zero', 'first', 'second', 'third']

def rank_text(self):
    nrank = getattr(self, 'nrank', None)
    if nrank is None:
        nrank = (Post.objects(author=self).count() + 9) // 10
    return RANK_TEXTS[nrank]


User.rank_text = property(rank_text)
```

So we *monkey patch* the `User` class such that it has a property `rank_text`. This will first look if we annotated the `User` with the `nrank` attribute. If that is *not* the case, we calculate the `nrank` manually. Finally we return the textual counterpart.

So we can for example query with:

```
u1 = User.objects.first()
u1.rank_text  # for example "second"
```

Se [here [so-post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django) how to monkey patch Django models.

Comment: but i need to specify the range too

Comment: @user: but what do you mean with "range"? You want to annotate every user with a number (the rank) that is between 1 and 3?

Comment: the user with total posts of 1-10 will be in category named 'First', 11-20 in 'Second' and so on

Comment: @user: and how do you exactly denote these categories (where are the constants "first", "second", etc.) stored?

Comment: just labels. I am not sure how to store and assign them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173023/discussion-between-user-and-willem-van-onsem).