# Overriding Django 3rd party library template tag to fix UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using the lean third party [Django google analytics](https://github.com/praekelt/django-google-analytics) library in a Django project of mine. This enables server side tracking via utilising the loading of a pixel image on each page request.

In this particular project, there exist some url patterns that may contain special (non-ascii) characters. E.g. example.com/user/яαχєя

The said library fails with the following error when the aforementioned uri (actualy [iri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier)) is encountered:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-10: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

I peeked at the third party library's relevant code - it's essentially a template tag included in my project like so:

```
{% load google_analytics_tags %}
<img src="{% google_analytics %}" width="1" height="1"/>
```

In the code, the library's template tag does the following (excerpt):

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def google_analytics(context, tracking_code=None, debug=False):
    request = context.get('request', None)
    path = request.path
    parsed_url = urlparse(path)
    """
    Some more processing comes here
    """
    return url
```

`parsed_url = urlparse(path)` is essentially where the problem occurs. I feel the quick fix/monkey patch here is to simply edit `parsed_url = urlparse(path.encode('utf-8'))`.

However, how do I override the 3rd party library's template tag in my code (in order to achieve the aforementioned)? Apologies in case it's a simple question - I haven't been able to unearth any documentation that solves my particular problem. Would be great to get an illustrative answer.

Comment: You might be able to [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django) your fix in, but I suggest to ditch the dependency on django-google-analytics, copy the code into your own code base and fix the error there. Chances are you forgot about the monkey patch you applied if/when django-google-analytics might be fixed in the future, which might result in hard to track errors. Alternatively, you can have a look if someone forked the project and fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jieter: fair enough, it's a minute change in any case. But this would give rise to a separate problem (I'm sure fully fixable). My package list via `pip freeze` would still show the original app (e.g. `django-google-analytics-app==4.3.0`). What's the best way to ensure subsequent installations don't erroneously install the original app, and always go for the fork instead?

Comment: We don't use `pip freeze`, but manage a `requirements.txt`, mainly using [`pur`](https://pypi.org/project/pur/). Pur doesn't touch rows with links to git repo's or zip files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing these bugs in poorly maintained third party libraries can be done using [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django), but the maintainability of such solutions is not great. (What happens if someone starts releasing new versions again? Do you remember the monkey patch? Does your college know?)

Instead, I suggest one of these approaches:

#### 1. Fork

Fork the library, fix it and point to the zipball/git url of your branch in your `requirements.txt`. If you have any hope the project will get active again, open a pull request in the original project for your fixes. Document this in your `requirements.txt` with something like this:

```
django==2.0.6
# Use fork of django-tables2 until https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/pull/566 is merged.
# django-tables2==2.0.0a1
https://github.com/fork/django-tables2/archive/master.zip
```

`pip freeze` will still show the orginal package name, so is not usable anymore. Instead, keep explicit versions of the packages you use in `requirements.txt`, use something like [pur](https://pypi.org/project/pur/) to bump versions.

#### 2. Vendor

Copy the relevant part of the library to your own project, and strip it to the bare minimum. You now have to maintain only the part you really use, without barriers of uptream maintainers. Only viable if the (part of the) library you need is small.