# Django list_per_page for all models in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Good day! I'm trying to find the solution to add list_per_page as a global parameter for all models in admin. I found out, that ModelAdmin has this parameter through ChangeList object and it has default value 100. But what if I want to set it 20 and it will be true for all models? I mean, if I need to change list_per_page for current model in admin, I need to add:

```
class CurrentModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 20
    ...
```

Is there any way to redefine ChangeList object to rewrite default value?
For example as a LIST_PER_PAGE = 20 in a settings.py

And even better, how I can recieve it from frontend and work with that dynamicly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you define a variable in your settings, for example:

```
# settings.py

# ...
LIST_PER_PAGE = 20
```

## Alter individual `ModelAdmin` classes

then in your views you can write:

```
from django.conf import settings

class CurrentModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = settings.LIST_PER_PAGE
```

## Define a baseclass with the `list_per_page` attribute set

It can be cumberome to write this for *every* `ModelAdmin` view, so you can for example first make a subclass that sets the `list_per_page`, and then subclass from that model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class BaseModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = settings.LIST_PER_PAGE

class CurrentModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    # ...
    pass
```

So now we do no longer need to specify the `list_per_page` attribute in every `ModelAdmin`, as long as we *subclass* from the `BaseModelAdmin`.

## Monkey patch the `ModelAdmin` class

You can also "monkey patch" the `list_per_page` attribute, and thus only update the value at the `ModelAdmin` level:

```
# app/monkey_patching.py

from django.conf import settings

ModelAdmin.list_per_page = settings.LIST_PER_PAGE
```

and follow the [steps to "activate" the monkey patching in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720858/how-to-monkey-patch-django).

Comment: Thank you very much, Willem! I decided to work with monkey patch. And it works like a charm for all models in admin! Great!