# How do you extend a Django third party model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, extend

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.0 and the django-address==0.2.1 module (https://pypi.org/project/django-address/).  The address module seems to auto-create migrations and import models for my app, which is nice.  I would like to create a

```
def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
    return self.get_or_create(...fields...)[0]
```

method for the AddressField model (for the purposes of making creation of YAML data easier).  Is it possible to add this into the AddressField model without altering the core files that download as part of installing this app?  The MySQL table created for that model is

```
+
| address_address | CREATE TABLE `address_address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `street_number` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `route` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `raw` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `formatted` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `locality_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `address_address_locality_id_5dd79609_fk_address_locality_id` (`locality_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `address_address_locality_id_5dd79609_fk_address_locality_id` FOREIGN KEY (`locality_id`) REFERENCES `address_locality` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------
```

although not sure how relevant this table structure is to my question.

Comment: Are you trying to add fields to the model? Or only add a new method?

Comment: If it's only the additional method, you're looking to monkey patch the model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668215/1637351

Comment: I'm only looking to add an additional method to the existing model.  This monkey_patch thing looks very promising.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: You can likely create a third party apps module that defines an app config, then wire up the new method in the `ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you want to `get_by_natural_key` function on model's manager and not in the model itself So that it is accessible like `Address.objects.get_by_natural_key`.

In order to achieve this, you can do

```
from django.db import models

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(...fields...)[0]

Address.add_to_class('objects', CustomManager())
```